# Create web clip for different URL

Tags: iphone, safari

Would it be possible to create a page where, if the user creates a web clip for it, the web clip points to a different URL?

For example, the user goes to `http://myincrediblewebapp.com`, which presents three radio buttons, A, B and C. Depending on the selection, when the user creates the web clip, it is actually pointing to `http://myincrediblewebapp.com/A`, `http://myincrediblewebapp.com/B` or `http://myincrediblewebapp.com/C`?

Of course I know of a bunch of other ways to create similar behavior, but my question is if it is possible to do exactly the above using some hack or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the records, I spent some time investigating this and it seems it is currently not possible.