# Is it possible to create a Home icon of a website on IOS that has custom parameters

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, web, safari

After research, I have found ways to "Add to Home Screen" option, but that only creates bookmarks for default website. I would like to include certain parameters in as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create web clip for different URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014431/create-web-clip-for-different-url)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't force the URL for the web clip, [this was asked a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014431/create-web-clip-for-different-url).

You can check the [iOS Safari Web Content Guide: Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW3) for more information on what you can edit.